# Can I bypass the username/PW using CURL with IIS windows authentication in php?

Tags: php, curl, windows-authentication

I was making a php log-in wrapper page to use the AD credential.

I tried use curl to post with NTLM auth and using my own `username:password` which is not supposed to be practical.

My current code looks like this, and it works now. Because this is under the same domain, I should be able to bypass the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` part and get rid of the `$username` and `$password` as well.

Can anyone suggest me how to do that?

```
<?php
$userName=$_SERVER['AUTH_USER'];
$userPassword=$userName;
$fields = array(
   "txtUserName" => "$userName",
   "txtPassword" => "$userPassword",
   "btn_login"=>'1'
);
//init curl function
$ch = curl_init();
$url='http://example.com/index.php';
$username="*****";
$password="*****";

// Enable HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1;         Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; InfoPath.2; SV1; .NET CLR 3.3.69573; WOW64; en-US)");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($output);
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Comment: solved by passing in empty username and password